# Will Malabar spinach regrow from being cut down to the ground?

Tags: vines, spinach

When I showed up at my garden patch today the Malabar Spinach plant went missing, so will the plant regrow from being cut down to the ground?

Comment: not very sciencey, but vines regrow... basically any plant that is thin and long is vulnerable to being snipped off

Comment: this is theft in community gardens

Comment: That is horrible... do you think somebody mistook it for morning glory / bindweed?

Comment: no, because the label was right in front of it as a showing them what this plant is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will. It's a very hardy vine, at least in India where it's a popular green for cooking.